# Multiple Data Template list view specific for Chat

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Can any body provide solution for the Multiple data template view in Xamarin forms to create chat structure?

Comment: You have first to code your solution because SO isn't a code service. I'll suggest to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: If you haven't tried anything, I would recommend using a third party for this. [SfChart](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/chat/getting-started)

Comment: As you provide too little information,do you want to look for [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector)

Comment: Yes and thanks I now received http://www.nullskull.com/a/10479347/listview-data-binding-with-mutiple-data-templates-in-xamarin-forms.aspx to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check temple selector for list view to make chat app

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector